# extracting highly similar proteins from a protein databases

Tags: bioinformatics, protein-database

How can I get from the PDB database highly highly similar structures?

Lets say 98% or higher sequence similar structures?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a particular protein you are interested in, you should first create a homology model to search through the database for similar proteins.  After doing this you can apply more stringent criteria to get results which are highly similar.  Check out Swiss Model to do this.  http://swissmodel.expasy.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a BLAST search (http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi) for your sequence, specifying the Protein Data Bank as the database you are searching.